# App icon not showing up on iPhone - Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

The iOS deployment target on the app is 11.1 and after adding the icon, I am noticing that the icon is not showing up. I came across other posts here on SO and seems like adding a profile to an image helped, but it didn't help me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why don't you add missing icons?

Comment: set all image specific size.

Comment: Why not upgrade to 9.2 it has many other fixes as well. Like 9.1 can't publish the app to AppStore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For app icon, icon sizes are very important. If you provide any size that not same as required then the icons are not showing properly. Read this document you will understand about app icon sizes.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/

You did not provide the actual size of icons as required. Please provide the actual size.

```
180px × 180px (60pt @3x)
120px × 120px (60pt @2x)

40px × 40px (20pt @2x)
20px × 20px (20pt @1x)
```

This link will help to create different size of icons you need.
https://makeappicon.com/

Comment: I had got confused with 60pt and I used 60px size icon for both 2x and 3x. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Read the warnings shown on the left in Xcode. Your icon images are the wrong size.

The 2x images needs to be 120x120 and the 3x image needs to be 180x180. You used a 60x60 image for both.

Remember, the icon needs to be 60 points (not pixels). 60 points is 120 pixels for 2x and 180 pixels for 3x.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having this issue on Xcode 10 beta 1, upgrade to beta 2 or later. It is mentioned in the changelog that this was an issue in beta 1. I had this exact issue on beta 1 and upgrading to beta 2 solved it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**May be useful to someone.**

I had the same problem on:

```
Xcode: 13.0
Min Deployment Target: 12.1
Device: iPhoneXs - 15.0.1
```

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/

Double, triple checked the icon sizes as per documentation. And recreated the App Icon as well. Spent lots of hours exploring SO, apple forums. Finally...

**The AppIcon started showing up just after *`restarting`* the device.**

**Update:** App icon started showing up on the device after upgrading `Xcode to 13.2.1.`

Answer (score 0):

Follow below link:

https://makeappicon.com/

**Note:**

Drag and drop 1024 x 1024 icon in above link. That site creates all size of icons and you can set icon Assets to AppIcon.

Hope this link helps you. :)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Check the plist maybe there is a different name for your appicon asset catalog.
If you you migrating old leagcy objective-c project to new assets catalogue, there could be a key in plist like "Icon files (iOS 5)". remove it. and keep only Appicon.
Check Build Settings - Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name.

Also sometimes helpful to delete the old app from ios device **then reboot** device and install again